# Are two instances of VelocityEngine really necessary in Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, velocity, spring-boot

I have a question about Velocity in Spring Boot app.

I use spring-boot-gradle-plugin, version 1.1.5.RELEASE and spring-boot-starter-velocity version 1.1.5.RELEASE too.

Via jvisualvm I've noticed that there are two instances of `VelocityEngine`. And indeed in [`VelocityAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/velocity/VelocityAutoConfiguration.java#L121) there are two beans created: `VelocityConfigurer`  (which internally creates `VelocityEngine`) and `VelocityEngine` itself (which is created via `velocityConfigurer.createVelocityEngine()`). Shouldn't it be   `velocityConfigurer.getVelocityEngine()` instead of `velocityConfigurer.createVelocityEngine()`?

`VelocityEngine`s are in the top 5 heaviest objects in my app, about 2MB of retained size each.

Comment: Pull requests welcome: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be fixed here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/95d65c2ff5ff9cbed7cdcb479618dc8f7ee9c39c (i.e. in 1.1.6).

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Maybe next time I will make it to submit my own pull request.